# anonymous event handler doesn't have access to prototype method

Tags: javascript

Can't access fx1 from fx2 inside an anonymous function handler?

```
var MyComponent = function () {
    //my constructor
}

MyComponent.prototype.fx1 = function() { //code }

MyComponent.prototype.fx2 = function() {

    var btn1 = document.getElementById('Button1')

    btn1.onclick = function() {
        //issue is here
        //trying to call fx1 from here but can't access it.

        this.fx1();  //doesn't work. 
    }
}
```

Comment: so what exactly did you try?

Comment: How where you accessing it?

Comment: You left out the code in question

Comment: @devnull69 - The OPs comment `trying to call fx1 from here but can't access it.` implies that he used `this.fx1();` but in his mockup made a typo.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As `this` is bound to the button within the `onclick` handler, you cannot use it to access the `MyComponent` instance. But you can simply save the reference in another variable which you then can use:

```
MyComponent.prototype.fx2 = function() {
    // save reference to the instance
    var self = this;

    var btn1 = document.getElementById('Button1')
    btn1.onclick = function() {
        // access the saved reference to the MyComponent instance
        self.fx1();
    }
}
```

Comment: The questions won't get any better if we keep answering questions that don't show the effort of the OP in the first place. But now it's fine, so be my guest :-)

Comment: @devnull69 To be honest, I immediately understood what the question was about and it was obvious enough for me. And btw., as a member of the community you are more than welcome to improve the question now that you know what it was about.

Answer (score 1):

Another way to do this:

```
MyComponent.prototype.fx2 = function() {
    var btn1 = document.getElementById('Button1');
    btn1.onclick = (function() {
        this.fx1();
    }).bind(this);
}
```